# Enviar checkbox seleccionado de una tabla php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

```
<tbody>
 <?php if(!empty($tarimas)): ?>
  <?php foreach($tarimas as $tarimas): ?>
     <tr role="row" class="odd">
     <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tarimas->id;?>" name='inputseleccion[]'><?php echo $tarimas->id; ?>
     </td>
     <td class="inputpeso"><?php echo $tarimas->peso; ?> kgs</td>
     <td class="inputcajas"><?php echo $tarimas->cajas; ?> cajas</td>
     <td>
   <div class="checkbox">
     <label>
         <input type="checkbox" value="" name='inputselect[]' class="chkseleccion"> Añadir
     </label>
   </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

traigo mis ids `$tarimas = $this->input->post('inputseleccion');`
tengo un array de checkbox llamado `inputselect[]` se puede ver. Pero **como valido si esta chequeado desde mi controlador?**

Comment: `$tarimas = substr(implode(', ', $this->input->post('inputselect')), 0)` mira a ver si te funciona.

Comment: me puede explicar un poco lo que hace?

Comment: Desde tu `imputselect` el `implode(..)` lo convertirá en una cadena de texto, y con el `substr` vas a extraer la cadena o parte de la cadena que necesitas. No soy experto en php lo siento si no te funciona